# django(v2.0.1) -- _str_() method shows Object but not notes in self.text(python3.5)

Tags: python, django

My models.py is like this:

[image: models.py]

My python's version is 3.5.x and django version is 2.0.1, and when I went to admin's page, I got this page:

[image]

Comment: this is my first use for stakoverflow, i think i make a mistake for adding images...  And thanks for your visit and answers.

Comment: You shouldn't be adding images at all. Post code as text, in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is much easier to help you if you just include the code in your answer.

The inherited method you are trying to override uses two underscores on both sides. Currently the inherited version of `__str__` is being used, not yours.

Try this:

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.text
```

Comment: thanks a lot, and i found this mistake when i read doc. Because of work, i learned python(work on java before), and i write python only on IDE, but this time on nodepad. i don't pay attention to this. And when i found this mistake, OMG... tow hours have been wasted...All in all, thank you all the same.

Comment: thanks again for making over my writing format, and i'll take care of it